# Solving $2\sin ^8x-\sin ^2x+6\cos x+6=0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$2\sin ^8x-\sin ^2x+6\cos x+6=0$$
I tried writing everything with respect to $\cos x=t$,

$$2(1-t^2)^4-(1-t^2)+6(t+1)=0$$
$$2(t+1)^4(t-1)^4+(t+1)(t-1)+6(t+1)=0$$
$$(t+1)[2(t-1)^4(t+1)^3+(t-1)+6]=0$$

Hence $\cos x=-1 \Rightarrow x=(2k+1)\pi$ is solution. But I can't find roots of $2(t-1)^4(t+1)^3+(t-1)+6$.

Comment: Can you show the polynomial is positive when $t$ is between $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks! We can rewrite it as $(t-1)(2(t^2-1)^3+1)+6$.And  $-2\le t-1\le 0$ and $-1\le(2(t^2-1)^3+1)\le1$ So their product can't be less than $-6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use $s$ for $\sin x$ and $c$ (your $t$) for $\cos x$. Your equation is equivalent to $$(2s^6-1)s^2 + 6(1+c) = ((2s^6-1)(1-c) + 6)(1+c) = 0$$
Since $s^2 \in [0,1]$, $|2s^6-1| \le 1$. Together with $|1-c| \le 2$, you have
$$|(2s^6-1)(1-c) + 6| \ge 6 - |(2s^6-1)(1-c)| \ge 6 - 2 = 4 > 0$$ This means $(2s^6-1)(1-c) + 6 \ne 0$ for all $x$ and hence your equation reduces to $$1 + c = 0\iff \cos x = -1$$